# scanning several numbers using Recursion and counting how many even numbers were scanned (in c)

Tags: c, recursion

the question is "write a recursive function that ends when -1 is entered, than return how many times an even number was scanned.

```
naturals(int);
static void main() {
    int num;
    printf("enter numbers\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    naturals(num);
}       

naturals(int num) {
    int count = 0;
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        count++;
    }
    if (num == -1) {
        printf("%d", count);
        return 0;
    }
    scanf("%d", &num);
    return naturals(num);
}
```

i know that it resets "count" to 0 at the start of the function, how do i solve this?

Comment: easy fix if you can change function signature: pass `count` as a parameter.

Comment: `void main()` wont win you the Turing award.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good place to make use of the `?:` operator:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int naturals(int count)
  {
  int num;

  scanf("%d", &num);

  return num == -1 ? count : naturals(num % 2 == 0 ? count+1 : count);
  }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  printf("enter numbers\n");
  printf("even numbers entered = %d\n", naturals(0));
  }
```

Here I'm passing `0` in as the initial count in the call to `naturals` in `main`, then for each number entered `count` is incremented if the number is even; otherwise we just pass the unincremented `count` to the next invocation of `naturals`. Prior to making the recursive call to `naturals` we check to see if the number entered is -1; if it is we return the current value of `count`, otherwise we proceed to make a recursive call to `naturals`.

If you prefer, the `return` line in `naturals` can be replaced with

```
  if(num == -1)
    return count;
  else if(num % 2 == 0)
    return naturals(count+1);
  else
    return naturals(count);
```

which is functionally the same. It has the disadvantage of having three separate `return` statements which IMO is more confusing, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep track of `count` *inside* your recursive function. As you have correctly observed, `count` is reset to 0 every time the function runs. Instead, you'll have to keep track of `count` outside of your function. Here are some ways of doing this:

1. Pass `count` as a parameter to your recursive function, update it, and have your recursive function return the new value;
2. Create a global variable `count` and update is as necessary every time the recursive function runs.

Comment: solution #1 should be #2 -- or even #42 :)

Comment: I agree with that. Swapped.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>l

naturals(int, int);
static void main() {
    int num, count = 0;
    printf("enter numbers\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    naturals(num, count);
}       

naturals(int num, int count) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        count += 1;
    }
    if (num == -1) {
        printf("%d\n", count);
        return 0;
    }
    scanf("%d", &num);
    return naturals(num, count);
}
```

solved it thanks!